# How can I use unescape() to include html custom char in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the word Cafe in my menu.  I want it to be Café

I have been playing around with Js's escape and unescape and I can't make it do whats I thought it could do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var newcafe = unescape('&eacute;');
        text = $(".cafe-menu-item").text().replace('cafe', 'caf' + newcafe);
        $(".cafe-menu-item").text(text);
    });
```

How to make this work?

Comment: The `escape` and `unescape` functions are for URL encoding, not HTML encoding. There aren't native HTML encoder functions in JavaScript. You can also directly embed Unicode characters in JavaScript strings.

Comment: @Pointy: depends on the editor being used... if I were writing my JS in Notepad for example, I wouldn't be able to directly embed the Unicode characters. (then again, who would be programming in Notepad?)

Comment: the issue was my escaping and it was easier to use unicode vs html chars.  Is it better to delete the question because it was a bad question or @Pointy do you want to answer and I'll approve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, just use a literal é in your code.

If you can't or don't want to do that, use a Unicode escape sequence:

```
var newcafe = "caf\u00e9";
```

JavaScript is not HTML.  Better not to try jamming HTML syntax in it if you can avoid it.

edit: Your example code misses the `var` on your `text` variable.